# Multiple graphics cards in X

Tags: xorg, nvidia, i915, bumblebee

I have a really interesting situation.

I'm on a Dell XPS 15z laptop, which features an NVIDIA Optimus display combination, using the integrated i915 Intel Graphics alongside an NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M discrete graphics card.

I'm not sure as to my current configuration, I'm not sure if my display is being driven by i915 or by `nouveau`. However, one thing doesn't work which is kind of important for my current setup. As noted [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15z), it appears that the HDMI-out port runs exclusively via the discrete NVIDIA card, so I don't even see the monitor in the display configuration:

[image]

The monitor reacts when being plugged in, but I simply don't see it.

Therefore, I need to determine the following:

- What's driving my current configuration, `i915` or `nouveau`?
- Is it possible to use Bumblebee to run both graphics cards and be able to power both the integrated graphics card (for the laptop monitor) and the discrete graphics card (for the HDMI-out) or find a way to run some configuration which will allow me to use everything as expected?

Comment: To your second question, I think the answer is yes (depending on your hardware). See the Bumblebee info [here](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup). You would have to get the NVIDIA card to run both screens.